# can somebody tell me the best practices for sending push notifications to millions of devices?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis

I am using `nodejs+mongodb` as backend. I wish to send push notifications to Android and IOS devices.On each user actions the notifications are send to his/her followers. The app has pretty good number of users and app's current installs is more tan 3 million.

I have done it before on `ASP.net` platform to limited number of devices.But when considering a large scale i'm pretty skeptic.

Do i need to implement any type of queuing?

Do i need to use Redis for this purpose?If yes for where?

Somebody plz suggest some nice libraries which might be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are using GCM/FCM it is advised that you could make calls to about 500 tokens per request.

So you can initialise a **thread for each 500** and that should be around 6000 jobs. You can also queue it in an manner that each executes after a constant time interval.

**chunks = user_base / 500**

**incremental_time = total_time_to_send / chunks**

Yes Redis could be a faster way to process the data if you would want to send to the entire data base in few minutes.

For your reference you could try these: https://github.com/taskrabbit/node-resque

Hope it helps!!